# Quote default values in create table SQL Server command

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to write a C# method that creates a table and adds a column. The default values for the column is given as argument to the method. What is the safest way to quote the default value in the SQL command?

The code would be something like this:

```
var defaultValueThatOriginatesFromAnEvilSource = "'; DROP TABLE #Entities; SELECT '"; // the argument
database.RawExecute(string.Format("create table #Entities (somecolumn int default {0})", defaultValueThatOriginatesFromAnEvilSource));
```

Would a simple replace of the single quotes in the argument take care of all types of injection? Or is there a special method in C# or SQL I should use for this?

One thing to note, is that I create a temp table, and I need that to be accessible to the the next SQL statement (using the same connection).

Comment: @shA.t how is that? can you give me a sample? :)

Comment: @shA.t you can't use parameters in a `create table` statement

Comment: Why are you creating tables on behalf of your users, and not on behalf of your program? Meaning, who needs that table and why?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It's for a migration tool, where I want to give the user a limited abstraction for creating tables. Unfortunately I can not limit the users ability to supply default values for the columns.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen to elaborate on that. The programmer of a system that uses my tool, writes a migration in a simple internal DSL, which issues some commands to migrate schema and content.

Answer (score 0):

As what shA.t said you can do this by sqlcommand in C# though it's quite hardwork if you'll be having multiple columns

but here's how to do it using stored procedure in SQL and sqlcommand in C#

in SQL

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CreateTable
          @TableName VARCHAR(50),
          @ColumnName VARCHAR(50)   
    AS
    BEGIN
          DECLARE @SQLCreate VARCHAR(MAX)
          SET @SQLCreate ='CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName
                                          + '('+@ColumnName+')'

    EXEC (@SQLCreate)

    END
    GO
```

---

and in C#

add this using directives

```
using System.Data;  
using System.Data.Client;  

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your connection string here");  
con.Open();  
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CreateTable");  
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "someName";  
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "someColumnName";  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
con.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this won't work for temp tables. The table created inside the store procedure is not accessible to the next SQL command.

Comment: sorry for the very late response, what do you mean not accessible? because if the table is created, it will always be accessible you just need to specify the table name in the SQL command.

Comment: That is unfortunately not so for temp tables (the ones prepended with #). They will only exist for the current connection and somehow that won't be the same inside the stored procedure as the one issuing the original command. The created temp tables will be gone by the time the store procedure ends.